# How to put an iframe inside a view on Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, view, drupal-views, drupal-8

I have a page on Drupal, and I need to put an embedded page that renders a 360 img, like an iframe, on a view:

[image: An example]

I looked for it on the internet but have not found a solution. I created a tag on that view but I don't know where to put my iframe code to render it.

This is my config tag view:

[image: config tag]

Comment: WHY ARE YOU SHOUTING AT US?

Comment: No sorry , im no shouting, i only look help to this issue, i fix that shouting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my case, i create a block and i put the iframe code inside them, after i configure the block to show where i want

[This is the creation block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0yRB.png)

But creating views, does not work because that don't let me modify the content

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using a body field in your view so I guess you'll want to add the iframe to that field?
If thats the case, you can enter the iframe code in your body and put the format on "FULL HTML", you might want to look into your WYSIWYG settings (/admin/config/content/formats in D8) to verify if the iframe tag is allowed.

There's also the option of using the iframe module (https://www.drupal.org/project/iframe) which allows you to add an iframe field.

Good luck

Comment: I try to find the way to put inside field body my code but i dont see the button that open the editor. then i try other thing, but thanks for help me